# How can errors be reported to Sentry from an Arduino-based microcontroller?

Tags: c++, arduino, sentry, freertos

There do not seem to be any lightweight and dependency-free libraries for error and crash reporting for programs written for the Arduino framework.

What possibilities are there to integrate a WiFi-enabled microcontroller, such as an ESP8266 or ESP32, with Sentry? Would this solution include

- Commit information?
- Only manual error checking or also crash reporting?
- Be lightweight enough for 80KB or 320KB of RAM?

N.B. FreeRTOS is used as the OS on these microcontrollers

Comment: ImO, an ESP8266 running FreeRTOS is not "Arduino-based". _Arduino_ does not know exceptions or even crashes.

Comment: It's the other way around, the Arduino framework is built on FreeRTOS, in the case of the ESPs. Exceptions are not available, as is the case for most microcontrollers, but can be enabled.